# Querying a Column in a Google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've setup a script to copy and process a spreadsheet that is generated from a form.

I gather the responses like this:

```
  var responses = formResponses.getDataRange().getValues();
```

Then accessing the individual columns through the array index, for example:

```
  var timestamp = row[0];
  var agentName = row[1];
```

Now, while this works. Any changes to the form could end up screwing the whole thing up and the array indices will change.

Can I instead query by column name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If accessing it via the `onFormSubmit event` is not viable for you because you need to access the data post-submission, I have created code that allows you to access via column name.

```
function getDataFields(workingRow){
    //header is row 1 -- not row 0
    var headerRow = 1;
    var headerRowValues = getRowRange(headerRow).getValues();
    var workingRowValues = getRowRange(workingRow).getValues();
    var dataFields = [];

    for (var colNum in headerRowValues[0]){
        dataFields[headerRowValues[0][colNum]] = workingRowValues[0][colNum];   
    }
    dataFields['Working Row'] = workingRow;

  return dataFields;  
}

function getRowRange(workingRow){
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lastColumn = activeSheet.getLastColumn();
  return activeSheet.getRange(workingRow, 1, 1, lastColumn);
}
```

You can then use dataFields['Column Name'] to access the data of that particular row.

Answer (score 0):

if you use the `onFormSubmit event` you can access all form values by their named values, this is explained in [the documentation on Spreadsheet Form Submit Events](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_events?hl=fr-FR) so you won't have this problem anymore...